# Getting data from selected row in NSTableView linked with Core Data

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

Hey,
So i am working on a Core Data app and I have an NSTableView linked with the Core Data. The table has three columns. Name, Position, Salary. I also set up a double click action. now what I need is that when I double click on a row i get the three values of that row.
I can do the following:

```
NSArray* myArray = [arrayController selectedObjects];
NSLog(@"%@", [myArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

But the output I get there is:

```
 (entity: Employees; id: 0x617890  ; data: {
    Name = "Joe";
    Position = "Manager";
    Salary = "1";
```

Is there a way to get those seperated?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
NSArray* selectedObjects = [arrayController selectedObjects];
NSLog(@"%@", [selectedObjects objectAtIndex:0]);

NSEntityDescription *entity = [selectedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", [entity valueForKey:@"Name"]);
```

Comment: or: NSArray *selectedObjects = [arrayController selectedObjects]; NSLog(@"%@", [[selectedObjects objectAtIndex:0] Name]); That is if you are sure that the entity has the property "Name".